# Did Windows 11 break Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, windows-11

I 'upgraded' my Win10 system to Win11. Since then Visual Studio Code simply will not run my PowerShell scripts. What happens is the little 'Pause/Step-x/Restart/Stop' ribbon appears at the top. All I can do then is hit the Stop. I uninstalled & re-installed VS-Code to no avail. I deleted the .vscode folder in my user-profile, again to no avail.

I have both PowerShell 5.1.22000.65 Desktop and 7.1.3 Core installed on this system. VS Code is 1.58.2 (system setup). PowerShell extension is v2021.6.2.

The same scripts run happily in Windows Terminal, PowerShell command window and the ISE.

Any ideas please?

Thanks very much.

Update 13th August 2021: PowerShell scripts are now running as expected in Visual Studio Code.
VS Code is 1.59.0.
PowerShell Extension is 2021.8.0.
The most likely change to have enabled scripts to work again is the update to PowerShell 7.1.4 Core (was 7.1.3).